# consult with typeahead.js database

Tags: javascript, php

Would like to query the database with typeahead.js v.0.10.2 .
I tried ,but I failed, I've bundled with the plugin.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
                name: 'user-search',
                remote: 'data.php' // you can change anything but %QUERY
                minLength: 1, // send AJAX request only after user type in at least 3 characters
                limit: 10 // limit to show only 10 results  
 });
});
```

PHP:

```
$dato = $_POST['query']; 

 require("connect.inc.php");//database



$query = mysql_query("SELECT artist FROM music WHERE artist REGEXP '^$dato'");

$array = array();


    while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $array = $fila['artist'];
    }


return json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Your code is brutally vulnerable to SQL injection, and you're using `mysql_query` which is deprecated and being removed from the language. Consider PDO and parameterized queries.

Comment: Sorry, well my question is in the script. 
How would the code structure to obtain the array sending by PHP and pass the data to typeahead?

Comment: To add to @meagar's point, swap the `$dato = $_POST['query'];` above for `$dato = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query']);` for a bit of safety. You should move it after your connection call too, as the escaping system needs a live connection to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `return json_encode($array);` use `echo return json_encode($array);`

Comment: Do you mean `echo json_encode($array)` here? `echo return` will result in a parse error.